# A bug? a well-populated vector<Mat> inside a while-statement changes unexpectedly its content when exiting the loop

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

The problem is the following:

On the one hand, I populate a vector with all frames of a video. I check if the frames actually contain those of the video, in the right order: YES.

On the other hand, when I exit the while-statement, and read with a for-loop its contents, it behaves as if every single frame was equal to the last frame of the video (a vector of repeated images).

I cornered the problem and found these facts:

- Every image is correctly read and stored in frame_temp (each frame is retrieved, from the beginning of the video until the end).
- imshow(frames[i]) shows the correct image inside the while loop.
- imshow(frames[i]) shows only the last frame of the video inside the for loop, whatever the value of "i" is.

I have tried doing it with vector.push_back, but the result is the same.

```
void GetFramesFromVideo(String filepath, vector<Mat>& frames)
{
    Mat frame_temp;
    VideoCapture cap = VideoCapture(filepath);
    int videosize = cap.get(7);
    frames = vector<Mat>(videosize);
    bool success = cap.read(frame_temp);
    frames[0]=frame_temp;
    namedWindow("he");
    int i = 1;
    while (success)
    {
        success = cap.read(frame_temp);
        if (success)
        {
            frames[i] = frame_temp;
            i++;
        }
        imshow("he", frames[i-1]);
        waitKey(10);
        cout << "Read a new frame: " << success;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++)
    {
        imshow("he", frames[i]);
        waitKey(10);
    }
}
```

- The imshow("he") inside the while-loop reproduces the video - each frames[i] is an actual frame of the video.
- The imshow("he") inside the for-loop repeats the last frame of the video again, and again. The frames vector seems to be populated with duplicates of the last "push_backed" frame.

Comment: There are two many functions there that you haven't shown, and which could be doing anything - including causing the problem.   The behaviour you describe is consistent with objects that share data, rather than copying by value.  Read up on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Peter: `Mat` is a principle type in OpenCV, as this question is tagged.  It's not fair to blame OP for not defining Mat, as more than it would be for not defining vector in a generic C++ question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck True, you wouldn't define them from scratch, you'd `#include` the appropriate header, as well as namespace-qualify the types, or at least not omit the `using namespace` that's obviously lurking in OPs code. Make the example complete, as in it compiles without any faffing about with the source code.

Comment: @DanMašek I disagree. This is just a code snippet, not a "c++ programme". Take cout and cin as an example, nobody cares about the include and the namespace, it is crystal-clear what the code says and what the code snippet omits. If I used functions using not-standard libraries, you're right! but not in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::Mat` is a type which has reference semantics, not value semantics.  In other words, you can think of it as a smart pointer to a matrix.

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302) for `operator=(const Mat&)` says:

> Matrix assignment is an O(1) operation. This means that no data is copied but the data is shared and the reference counter, if any, is incremented.

So your problem is simple: you are always writing to `frame_temp`, which is the only actual data you have, and then you are storing references to that data repeatedly in your `vector<Mat>`.  You need to create a new `Mat` each time.

Comment: You don't need to `clone()`, that's a waste of efficiency.  Instead, simply `cap.read(frames[i])` and you'll incur no extra copies.  Get rid of `frame_temp` entirely.